# Scrapy - Archive and zip all downloaded images

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to download images from a large online database. I have used `ImagesPipeline`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = './images'
```

And it works like a charm!

**Problem:** I have *lots* of images pilling up in the `images` folder (>100000). I was wondering if there was a way to handle that volume a bit more nicely:

- When a new image is downloaded, append it to an archive, and, when the crawling is completed, compress the archive.

**OR**

- After a number of images have been downloaded (say, 1000), store those images in a new folder of their own.

**OR**

- A combination of the two options above (e.g. archive files in bulks of ~1000).

The idea is really to make it more easy to manipulate, move, edit, index, search the downloaded data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own extension to the ImagesPipeline so I would suggest to do this and implement the solution as you wish.

You can start with counting the exported images and create a new sub-folder to download to after each 1000 (or as you set up) and then zip it or for example after creating a new folder spawn a new process which creates an archive of the older folder's contents.

You can read more about extending the pipelines in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#module-scrapy.pipelines.files).

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a little bit on how to do that ? The image pipeline automatically stores pictures in a predefined folder, and can potentially create thumbnails. How do you extend ImagesPipeline without messing with this process?

Comment: I was also wondering: To avoid messing with ImagesPipeline, maybe there's a way to create another pipeline acting when ImagesPipeline is done, as a sort of post-processor...?

Comment: With the usage of `item_completed()` you can add another pipeline ordering it later than the default ImagesPipeline and then you can look up the images in the folder and move them to a new one or do something else. So you do not mess-up the core functionality of the already working one. Or you can have one and call the superclass's method inside yours and then do the custom logic.